# Swift: Value Changing Control Events Not Calling?

Tags: ios

So I have added targets to my IBActions I have created that occur when the value of a text field changes. When these actions occur, the system should check if the two text fields are both integers. I have set two variables set to false, and they are set to true when both of them are an int. In the IBActions, I have if statements that tell a button to be enabled if both of the variables contain integers. When I run the simulator, this button doesn't enable when both of the text fields contain an integer.

I am new to swift, so if possible, please write all of the code out and where it should be in my code. Here is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var calculatorButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var inspirationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beginningLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calculatorContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var answer1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourWeightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var calorieNumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var menuExampleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var aboutButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    yourWeightTextField.delegate = self
    calorieNumberTextField.delegate = self
    calculateButton.enabled = false
    // Calling the textfield valueChanged Methods
    yourWeightTextField.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged);
    calorieNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action:"calorieNumberValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func calculatorButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    calculatorContainer.hidden = false
    inspirationLabel.hidden = true
    beginningLabel.hidden = true
    menuExampleButton.hidden = true
    aboutButton.hidden = true
}

var yourWeightFilled = false
var calorieNumberFilled = false

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    // If the textfields have the properties of the function
    if textField == yourWeightTextField {
        yourWeightFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    } else if textField == calorieNumberTextField {
        calorieNumberFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    }

    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}

// The methods to close the keyboard when editing is finished
@IBAction func yourWeightEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    yourWeightTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    calorieNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func yourWeightValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
@IBAction func calorieNumberValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    // If both variables are true and the text fields contain integers, enable button
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should look for `EditingChaged` event, not `ValueChanged`

EDIT:
What I mean is to change from:

```
yourWeightTextField.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged);
calorieNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action:"calorieNumberValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged);
```

to :

```
yourWeightTextField.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);
calorieNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action:"calorieNumberValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);
```

You simply are looking for wrong event.

Comment: You forgot an 'n' on 'EditingChanged' in the second code sample.

Comment: @Piotr but it just works when I'm editing textfield with keyboard. what should I do when  I need to change textfield with a button click?

Comment: @MHSFisher Then just call action method (e.g. yourWeightValueChanged) from button action method manually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a  **text changed event** , then **Right Click** on the **text field** select  **Editing Did End** from the **Sent Events** . You can see a **circle on the right** end **click the circle Hold Down Ctrl and Drag it to your ViewController file**. **Name the Action** you want and **[image: Click connect]**. I have provided some screen shots for this.
Here i name the Action **TextChanged**

I am Using Xcode 7 Swift 2 here

Right Click on the Text Box and You can see Something Like this
[image][image]

Finally You can see the TextChanged event Created. when you type something on a text box and click return this event fires.